# setTimeout and setInterval time management

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function that prints 'Hello, World!' every second for 5 minutes, and after 5 minutes, this function will stop for 1 minute. I want to create a loop like this with **setTimeout** and **setInterval**, but I couldn't. Can anyone help me?

```
const helloWorld = () => console.log("Hello, World!")

const stopSayHello = () => console.log("Stopped for a minute!")
```

The HelloWorld function will run every second for 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, the stopSayHello function will run for a minute. Then, this loop will continue.

Comment: you can use `setInterval` with `1000` to print the line each second while keeping track of how many times it occurred.. and add a condition that will clear the timer (at 60*5 times) and will wait for 1 minute with `setTimeout` before launching the same loop again

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `setInterval` or `setTimeout` for precise timing over any significant period, and I certainly wouldn't want to juggle starting/stopping intervals.  Instead, have one ongoing interval which invokes your logic every second (or more often) indefinitely.  Then in that logic you can calculate whether or not to display anything based on the current time and a value you stored for when the timer began.

Comment: "*but I couldn't*" - can you show us your attempt, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const helloWorld = () => console.log("Hello, World!");
const stopSayHello = () => console.log("Stopped for a minute!");

const runHelloWorld = () => {
  // Run helloWorld every second for 5 minutes
  const helloInterval = setInterval(() => helloWorld(), 1000);
  
  // After 5 minutes, stop saying hello and wait for 1 minute
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(helloInterval);  // Stop the helloWorld interval
    stopSayHello();               // Print the stop message
    // After 1 minute, restart the loop
    setTimeout(() => runHelloWorld(), 60000);
  }, 300000);  // 5 minutes in milliseconds
};

// Start the loop
runHelloWorld();
```

This code sets up an initial setInterval to call the helloWorld function every second. After 5 minutes (300,000 milliseconds), it clears the interval, prints the stop message, and sets a setTimeout to restart the loop after 1 minute (60,000 milliseconds). This process repeats indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function `startTimer` that will initiate the procedure...

it will use `setInterval` to invoke `helloWorld` each second.. while keeping track of the number of times it occurred. When such counter hits `5*60` (1 minute) it clears the interval and prints it will be waiting for 1 minute.. by doing `setTimeout` and restarting the whole `startTimer` after such amount of time.

The question is: such approach will overflow the call stack? Legit question but the `setTimeout` is expected to return immediately anwyay so there's no infinite calls through the stack.

```js
const helloWorld = () => console.log("Hello, World!")
const stopSayHello = () => console.log("Stopped for a minute!")

var seconds = 0;

var timer;
startTimer();

function startTimer(){
  timer = setInterval(()=>{
    seconds += 1;  
    helloWorld();
    if (seconds == 5*60){
      seconds = 0;
      clearInterval(timer);
      stopSayHello();
      setTimeout(startTimer, 1000*60);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I add code below.

```js
const helloWorld = () => console.log("Hello, World!");
const stopSayHello = () => console.log("Stopped for a minute!");

const runLoop = () => {
  let timePassed = 0;

  // Run helloWorld every second until 5 minutes pass
  const helloInterval = setInterval(() => {
    helloWorld();
    timePassed += 1000;

    // After 5 minutes, stop helloWorld and run stopSayHello
    if (timePassed >= 5 * 60 * 1000) {
      clearInterval(helloInterval);
      stopSayHello();

      // After 1 minute, restart the loop
      setTimeout(runLoop, 60 * 1000);
    }
  }, 1000);
};

// Start the loop
runLoop();
```